# R: subtracting subsequent rows for a select amount of values

Tags: r

This is the data I currently have:

```
df

patient ID  Index_admission?    adm_date    dish_date
1244             FALSE           2/7/2009   2/8/2009
1244             TRUE            3/5/2009   3/15/2009
1244             FALSE           4/5/2011   4/7/2011
1244             FALSE           3/25/2012  3/27/2012
1244             TRUE            5/5/2012   5/20/2012
1244             TRUE            9/8/2013   9/15/2013
1244             FALSE           1/5/2014   1/15/2014
2333             FALSE           1/1/2010   1/8/2010
2333             FALSE           1/1/2011   1/5/2011
2333             TRUE            2/2/2011   2/25/2011
2333             FALSE           1/25/2012  1/28/2012   
5422             TRUE            3/5/2015   3/15/2015   
1243             TRUE            2/5/2009   2/8/2009
1243             TRUE            2/5/2011   2/19/2011
```

I need to find the `time_to_readmission` from the previous `Index_admission`. I will need to add a new column which subtracts the `adm_date` from the correct `dish_date`. This should only be done if the patient has already has had a `TRUE` for `Index_admission`.

**ALSO** the time_to_readmission should always be calculated to the nearest `Index_admission` date if the patient has multiple `Index_admission`.

Probably easier to explain though looking at how I want the data to look:

```
df1

patient ID  Index_admission?    adm_date    dish_date   time_to_readmission
1244             FALSE           2/7/2009   2/8/2009    NA
1244             TRUE            3/5/2009   3/15/2009   NA
1244             FALSE           4/5/2011   4/7/2011    751
1244             FALSE           3/25/2012  3/27/2012   1106
1244             TRUE            5/5/2012   5/20/2012   1147
1244             TRUE            9/8/2013   9/15/2013   476
1244             FALSE           1/5/2014   1/15/2014   112
2333             FALSE           1/1/2010   1/8/2010    NA
2333             FALSE           1/1/2011   1/5/2011    NA
2333             TRUE            2/2/2011   2/25/2011   NA
2333             FALSE           1/25/2012  1/28/2012   334
5422             TRUE            3/5/2015   3/15/2015   NA
1243             TRUE            2/5/2009   2/8/2009    NA
1243             TRUE            2/5/2011   2/19/2011   727
```

Please help me with the required coding.  Thanks in advance.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(patient.ID = c(124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 
124L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 233L, 542L, 1243L, 1243L), Index.admission. = c(FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), adm_date = structure(c(8L, 10L, 12L, 9L, 13L, 
14L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 11L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("1/1/2010", 
"1/1/2011", "1/25/2012", "1/5/2014", "2/2/2011", "2/5/2009", 
"2/5/2011", "2/7/2009", "3/25/2012", "3/5/2009", "3/5/2015", 
"4/5/2011", "5/5/2012", "9/8/2013"), class = "factor"), dish_date = structure(c(7L, 
8L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 5L), .Label = c("1/15/2014", 
"1/28/2012", "1/5/2011", "1/8/2010", "2/19/2011", "2/25/2011", 
"2/8/2009", "3/15/2009", "3/15/2015", "3/27/2012", "4/7/2011", 
"5/20/2012", "9/15/2013"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("patient.ID", 
"Index.admission.", "adm_date", "dish_date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: use `dput` to provide your example data vs pasting it.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?  _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To be honest I have not tried anything.  I am very new to R and not really quite sure where to even start.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Note that i get a `data.table` type-error when I run it, but the answer is correct.

One caveat here is that this calculates the time to readmit from the first `dish_date` meeting your criteria, which is what you request in the post *"subtracts the `adm_date` from the `dish_date` (of a previous row) ". You don't specify which previous row... I'm taking the first `dish_date` meeting your criteria.*

From you example output, that's not exactly what you're doing. Instead, it appears you have some unclear criteria on how to choose the "of a previous row." It's not clear what this rule is. Clarify the question if you want a different output

```
calc_readmit <- function(df) {
  if (nrow(df) == 1) return(NA)
  admitted <- c(0,cumsum(df$Index_admission))
  admitted <- admitted[-length(admitted)]
  dt1 <- df$dish_date[min(which(admitted > 0))-1]
  admit2 <- ifelse(admitted > 0, dt1, NA)
  time <- as.integer(df$adm_date) - admit2
  as.integer(ifelse(admitted > 0, time, NA))
}

library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df, key= "id")
df <- df[, time_to_readmission := calc_readmit(.SD), by= "id"]

R> df
      id Index_admission.   adm_date  dish_date time_to_readmission
 1: 1243             TRUE 2009-02-05 2009-02-08                  NA
 2: 1243             TRUE 2011-02-05 2011-02-19                 727
 3: 1244            FALSE 2009-02-07 2009-02-08                  NA
 4: 1244             TRUE 2009-03-05 2009-03-15                  NA
 5: 1244            FALSE 2011-04-05 2011-04-07                 751
 6: 1244            FALSE 2012-03-25 2012-03-27                1106
 7: 1244             TRUE 2012-05-05 2012-05-20                1147
 8: 1244             TRUE 2013-09-08 2013-09-15                1638
 9: 1244            FALSE 2014-01-05 2014-01-15                1757
10: 2333            FALSE 2010-01-01 2010-01-08                  NA
11: 2333            FALSE 2011-01-01 2011-01-05                  NA
12: 2333             TRUE 2011-02-02 2011-02-25                  NA
13: 2333            FALSE 2012-01-25 2012-01-28                 334
14: 5422             TRUE 2015-03-05 2015-03-15                  NA
```

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for.  I need the `time_to_readmission` to be from the calculated based on the `dish_date` of the nearest `index_admission`.  For example, the value 1638 should be 476 because the nearest index admission dish_date was 2012-05-20.

Comment: @MitchellCoplan Sorry, I've already spent too much time on this (I ended up having to debug a `data.table` error for 10-15 minutes). You should be able to modify my code easily to meet your exact needs. You just need an additional clause for your more restrictive criteria.... Your original question was unclear; I answered it as clearly as was possible.